# Problem with Tailwind CSS Arbitrary Values in React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Am I getting this wrong somehow? This is the most basic example I can give.
The result is that the class does not have any effect.

```
<div className="text-[42px]">Hello World!</div>
```

See Tailwind's documentation
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values

I am using Tailwind version 3.0.13.

This is my tailwind.css file.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Do other tailwind classnames work such as `px-4` ? Also provide your tailwind setup to make debugging easier.

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw - Yes, normal Tailwind classnames works well. I have added the Tailwind config file to the question.

Comment: It seems like some other people are having this issue recently - https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/6988

Comment: Seems to be working fine on the playground. Do you have more configuration files to share? Like `tailwind.config.js` or `postcss.config.js`.

Comment: Just tried a [fresh install](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app) and `text` arbitrary values are working fine. I suggest you double checking your configuration files.

Comment: @Camilo Thanks, maybe I have to try test a fresh install then. I upgraded TW from v2.14 but otherwise there is no dirt in the code. The config files looks exactly as in the installation guide for React. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Comment: Make sure you followed the [Upgrade Guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide).

Comment: Have you made sure the path glob in the `content` property targets the file you're editing?

Comment: @Shreshth, Yes, otherwise other Tailwind classes wouldn't work, which they do.